# Stop browsers to autopopulate remembered username and password in the from

Tags: html

The browser has remembered username and password for a website. So, when any form on that website opens and contains username and password fields, it auto populates those with the remembered username and password. What code should I add to those forms or fields, so that it will not auto populate the fields with those information?

Comment: Did you try a search of the question before posting?

Comment: Seems `autocomplete = "off"` works for every browser except recent FireFox browsers - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/How_to_Turn_Off_Form_Autocompletion

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw. Yes, I did. Did you find this a duplicate of some other post?

Comment: autocomplete="off" works on all fields, but it does not work on those fields which are auto-populated by the browser. I am using Google Chrome Version 35.0.1916.153.

Comment: Sorry misunderstood the specifics of your question. Thought you were talking about auto-fill-in not auto-populate. Only found references to people saying they had no solution either. I would suggest using Javascript to check if any textfields change without user input and if they do then reset them to blank.